# Sinatra - 4.0.1 unable to load JQuery - net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, ruby, http-status-code-404, sinatra

I'm absolutely stumped.
I'm trying to load a simple html view using Sinatra, but the console is providing the following errors;
[image]

I'm under the impression that it can't find the JQuery file, however it is where the address points to.

[image]

Below is the index.html that is trying to call it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Thermostat</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/src/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <h1 id="temperature"></h1>
  <p>
    <button id="temperature-up">+</button>
    <button id="temperature-down">-</button>
    <button id="temperature-reset">reset</button>
    </br>
    <button id="powersaving">Change Power Saving Mode</button>
    power saving mode is <span id="power-saving-status">ON</span>
  </p>

    <h1>Current temperature: <span id="location-temperature"></span></h1>
    <h1>Chance of rain: <span id="chance-of-rain"></span>%</h1>
 </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Current temperature: <span id="second-temperature"></span></h1>
    <h1>Chance of rain: <span id="chance-of-rain-second-location"></span>%</h1>
    <select id="current-city">
      <option value="london">London</option>
      <option value="glasgow">Glasgow</option>
      <option value="paris">Paris</option>
      <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/src/interface.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Sinatra app.rb file
    require 'sinatra/base'
    require 'json'

```
class Thermostat < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
   File.read('index.html')
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

And, below is the interface.js file that will use JQuery

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('Hello World');
});
```

What do I need to do, to get index.html to load the .js files?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it appears that Sinatra was having issue locating my static files.
I was told to read [How to Include Images, CSS, and/or Javascript in Your Sinatra Web Application](https://medium.com/@kerenlerner/how-to-include-images-css-and-or-javascript-in-your-sinatra-web-application-45e2ebbfa75f)

The solution was to put the javascript into a new folder, ./public
This has eliminated both the console errors.